# How can I find all the commits that have multiple parents in a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a research to study merges in open source projects.

For each merge in the repo I need to find the base (nearest common ancestor), the two contributors, and the resulting merged commit.

I already have an idea of how to get the nearest common ancestor (`hg debugancestor rev1 rev2` or `hg log -r 'ancestor(rev1, rev2)'`) and the contributors, but I am having problem identifying the commits that resulted from a merge operation.

How can I find all the commits that have more than one parent in a Mercurial repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `merge()` revset or the `-m` command tail to `hg log`

```
hg log -r 'merge()'
```

or

```
hg log -m
```